# Error with ejabberd and xmlrpc

Tags: xml-rpc, ejabberd

I installed ejabberd 14.07 + ejabberd xmlrpc using the manual. But always getting errors
Error -112 Unknown call: {call,check_password, [{struct,[{user,"admin"}, {host,"host"}, {password,"1234567"}]}

Comment: What is the XML-RPC structure you are sending ?

Comment: same problem here, read this line: Since ejabberd 2.1.0, the code in mod_xmlrpc has been reorganized: mod_xmlrpc provides only a few test XML-RPC calls and access to ejabberd commands. All the calls that were implemented in the old mod_xmlrpc has been moved to a new module: mod_admin_p1. So, in ejabberd 2.1.0 and newer it is required to enable mod_admin_p1 which provides all the calls.Also note that most calls have changed the arguments and/or result. So please update the XML-RPC calls according to this updated documentation.